# Tabbarcontroller with navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am adding view controller in navigation controller and then adding it to tab bar controller. but if i add this like

```
navigationController.viewControllers = 
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootViewController, rootViewController.photoViewController, nil];


tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tourNavigation,mapNavigation ,browserNavigation,
                                        navigationController,nil];
```

This is not showing tab with fourth navigation controller.. other controllers are simple as

```
BrowserViewController *browserView = [[BrowserViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BrowserViewController"
                                                                                bundle:nil];

    browserView.title = @"Browser";

    UINavigationController *browserNavigation = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:browserView]
                                                 autorelease];
```

This is working fine.. but navigation with array is not displaying.

Comment: Are you sure that none of the references are nil?

Comment: ya.actually I saw this code in appdelegate likerootViewController.photoViewController = [[PhotoViewController new] autorelease];
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        navigationController.viewControllers = 
            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootViewController, rootViewController.photoViewController, nil];
    }
    
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];

Comment: And I want to add this in tabbarcontroller.any idea?

Comment: My first guess was nil controller, Try creating a simpler example with just a basic navigation controller and see if that works.

Comment: the code which I posted in comment is working properly.for tab bar it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be setting the navigation controller's `viewControllers` array like that. Instead try:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
[navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController.photoViewController animated:NO];
```

This is assuming that you want the photo view controller to be showing when the user taps on the tab. It will be on top of the navigation controller's stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with view based application. And then create a UITabbarController in you appDelegate file.

Appdelegate.h

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
// set properties
```

Appdelegate.m

```
// Synthsize

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;

//Adding Search,Nearby,Map,AboutUs,Favorites Tabs to tabBarController  
Search * search = [[Search alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *searchNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:search];  

Nearby* nearby = [[Nearby alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *nearbyNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nearby];  

Map* map = [[Map alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *mapNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:map];  

AboutUs* aboutUs = [[AboutUs alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *aboutUsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUs];  

Favorites* favorites = [[Favorites alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *favoritesNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favorites];  

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchNav,nearbyNav,mapNav,aboutUsNav,favoritesNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;  

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

You can accordingly manage in which tab you want to place navigation controller or only a view controller.

Then in each of the view controllers mentioned above you need to implement

```
- (id)init {}
```

in which you can set Tab name and image.

Comment: My app is window based.And it is started with start page and I coded this line in start page's button.please tell if I can do this in windows based?

Comment: Hi. I am not sure about this. I never tries it on window application. And I am really sorry I cant try it today as I dont have my MAC with me. You may try it. Do write the result. It'll be useful for me too. Thanks :)